# How to know from which page/post was contact form sent

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts, quote

Hi have a kind of catalog system implemented with wordpress posts. Hi would like to create a "Get Quote" button on each post that would open on lightbox a small contact form. My challenge here is, how to get the information of from which page/post was contact form sent. Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden input in your contact form with a value of the name of the page for example:

```
<input type="hidden" value="contact-form-1" name="getpage">
```

and include it in your PHP:

```
$origin = $_REQUEST['getpage'];
```

and add it in the body of your 'mail' function.

Comment: I was looking for something more like having some code on Contact Form 7, on subject of contact form sent, to get de post name or something...

Comment: I think I will try this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-add-post-title-as-email-subject?replies=5